# Exception при выводе данных MySql в Listview...... (Volley library)

Tags: android, json, listview, исключения

```
public class Bus1 extends ListActivity {


String url = "http://10.0.0.2:8080/get_stations";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Item_List;
ProgressDialog PD;
ListAdapter adapter;
RequestQueue requestQueue;

public static final String ITEM_ID = "id";
public static final String ITEM_NAME = "name";
public static final String ITEM_CONTROLL = "controll";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Item_List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    PD = new ProgressDialog(this);
    PD.setMessage("Loading.....");
    PD.setCancelable(false);

    getListView();
    ReadDataFromDB();
}

private void ReadDataFromDB() {
    PD.show();
    JsonObjectRequest jreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        int success = response.getInt("success");

                        if (success == 1) {
                            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("stations");

                            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jobj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                item.put(ITEM_ID, jobj.getString(ITEM_ID));
                                item.put(ITEM_NAME, jobj.getString(ITEM_NAME));
                                item.put(ITEM_CONTROLL, jobj.getString(ITEM_CONTROLL));

                                Item_List.add(item);

                            } 

                            String[] from = {ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_CONTROLL};
                            int[] to = {R.id.item_id, R.id.item_name, R.id.item_controll};

                            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), Item_List,
                                    R.layout.item_list, from, to);

                            setListAdapter(adapter);

                            PD.dismiss();

                        } 

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            PD.dismiss();
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jreq);
}
}
```

вываливается

```
03-15 18:09:23.887 669-669/com.example.max777.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.max777.myapplication/com.example.max777.myapplication.Bus1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at com.example.max777.myapplication.Bus1.ReadDataFromDB(Bus1.java:104)
                                                                              at com.example.max777.myapplication.Bus1.onCreate(Bus1.java:49)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-15 18:09:24.197 669-674/com.example.max777.myapplication I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-15 18:09:24.237 669-674/com.example.max777.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-15 18:09:24.497 669-674/com.example.max777.myapplication I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-15 18:09:24.517 669-674/com.example.max777.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-15 18:09:31.926 669-669/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 669 SIG: 9
```

Comment: а 104 строчка на что указывает?  com.example.max777.myapplication.Bus1.ReadDataFromDB(Bus1.java:104)

Comment: Указывает на  Null pointer exception......  Из-за чего??

Comment: у вас `requestQueue` нигде не создается.

Comment: @zRrr при попытке создать requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()); ..... newRequestQueue подсвечивается красным

Comment: @zRrr спасибо разобрался, просто создавал requestQueue вне метода  ReadData()